# IIS server messed up

Tags: iis-7

I am having problems in making IIS server to work.I have tried uninstalling and installing the IIS . but, when i try to start the service, i get the error "cannot start service w3svc in computer ."

I have tried reinstalling 4-5 times,but same problem.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You will probably get more help over on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: That's not much information.  What do your logs say?

Comment: I closed this and didn't migrate to serverfault.com because there isn't sufficient concrete information about your problem other than you say IIS doesn't work. You need to be more specific about the problem you have, information such as what happened on the run up to this problem is extremely useful, whether you touched any knobs or dials in the servers config, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read about this issue [on this forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1151484.aspx). Maybe it will help you.